# checkbox in a json appended table not working

Tags: jquery, json, checkbox, append

My problem is, I have created a *json* table and the information is from a *mysql database*. That's not the problem anyway. i can display the information on the appended table, the checkboxes are there but!!!! only the first checkbox in the first row is working. here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'scripts/actions/get.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data,function(i,user){
        $('tr:odd').addClass('odd');
            var tblRow =
                "<tr>"
                +"<td><input name='chk' type='checkbox' id='chk' myid = "+user.id+"></td>"
                +"<td>"+user.id+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+user.name+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+user.principal+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+user.admin_contact_person+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+user.telephone_number+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+user.fax_number+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+user.contact_person_email+"</td>"
                +"</tr>";

                $(tblRow).appendTo("#tbody");

                });
            }
        });
```

Can some shade some light on this please... :)

Comment: When you say only the first checkbox is "working", what do you mean?

Comment: All your checkboxes have the same name. When you submit the form, how is the server supposed to tell which one was checked?

Comment: Also, you have two `id` attributes in the checkbox. That's not valid.

Comment: Also, you have two "id" attributes in your checkbox code.

Comment: @AnnL.
I tried 
 if($("#chk").is(':checked')){
 alert("something");
}
 
only when the first checkbox is selected, the alert is displaying

Comment: IDs must be unique, so ID selectors just return the first element with that ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
            +"<td><input name='chk[]' type='checkbox' class="chk" value='"+user.id+"'></td>"
```

You can then use

```
$(".chk:checked")
```

to get a collection of all the checkboxes that have been selected. You can iterate through them with `.each()` to get their values, to know which users have been checked.

Answer (score 1):

```
+"<td><input name='chk' type='checkbox' id='chk' id = "+user.id+"></td>"
```

issues:
you use id 2 times 
and if you need this to work in a form i suggest:

```
+"<td><input name='"+user.id+"' type='checkbox' id='chk'/></td>"
```

because you need different name for each checkbox...